# Getting a value from App.config file using System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection will add \\ to any \\ characters

Tags: c#, .net

We have the following value inside app.config for an asp.net console application:-

```
<add key="ConnectionString" value="Server=10.***\\engine;Database=ServiceDesk;Trusted_Connection=True;User ID=ad-***\\*****db.user;Password=***" />
```

where i have added `\\` inside the key value.. now i am using this code to get the value :-

```
public static string tokenGet(string key)
       {
           NameValueCollection settings = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("customAppSettingsGroup/customAppSettings")
            as System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection;

           if (settings != null)
           {           

             return settings[key];           

           }

          return String.Empty;
       }
```

but the code will return this value where it will add additional `\\`.. any advice how i can fix this ?

```
<add key="ConnectionString" value="Server=10.***\\\\engine;Database=ServiceDesk;Trusted_Connection=True;User ID=ad-***\\\\*****db.user;Password=***" />
```

Comment: It doesn't. That's just what you see in the IDE, as usual (escaped backslashes).

Comment: @Jimi no becuase my code will not work unless i write this `.Replace("\\\\","\\")`

Comment: `ConfigurationManager.GetSection()` returns exactly what you have written in those Keys. It doesn't add anything.

Comment: @Jimi but the values in my case are encrypted using `aspnet_regiis.exe` could this be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

OK, change it.

```
<connectionStrings>  
  <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Server=10.***\\engine;Database=ServiceDesk;Trusted_Connection=True;User ID=ad-***\\*****db.user;Password=***" />  
</connectionStrings>


var connection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString.Replace("\\","");
```

Comment: i am already using `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection`

Comment: <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString=.....